# Adding DLL file to Resources as content causes copying it to the bin output folder and BadImageFormatException on startup

Tags: visual-studio, reference, nuget, pre-build-event, badimageformatexception

I'm using the old VS 2015 Pro (C# project) and it seems like there is a bug or I don't understand something.
As I discovered by experimenting, **adding copies of a dll file (that is already referenced by project) into Resources (`bin\Debug\Resources`) as Content** (or None) **makes Visual Studio overwrite (replace) the referenced dll (in `bin\Debug` folder), causing BadImageFormatException** at startup. By including in Resources I mean adding instances of this:

```
<Content Include="Resources\NuGetPackageName\public\x64\DllName.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Removing these fixes the problem. Changing `Content` to `None` or `Always` to `Never` (or both) does not fix the problem. It does not make any sense to me. **Why is it copying the file to `bin\Debug` as well??**

I'm referencing the DLL from the packages folder (it's coming from NuGet package). Technically, I'm pulling 2 NuGet packages, they both contain x64 and x86 version of the same dll as content and (for each package) one of them (based on selected x86/x64 in VS) is getting copied by prebuild script into a special location inside each package (in `packages\PackageName\SpecialLocation` folder) and one of the two is used as reference in the project - don't ask why! I know it's crazy!). It was working fine until these additional copies in resources appeared - actually after adding another project to solution, because it was still working fine before it was added. The new project does not copy or reference this dll so it does not affect this). I've checked that the copy in `packages\PackageName\SpecialLocation`  is not getting overwritten incorrectly, so it's only the one in `bin\Debug` that is getting swapped.

Can you think of any reason for this happening?

Comment: It is the reference not the copy of the dll will be output to `bin\debug`. When you reference the DLL by project and then select `copy to local = true` in the properties view, this behavior will happen. If you set `copy always` to the copy dll, it will be output to `bin\Debug\Resources` rather than `bin\Debug`.

Comment: l think you are using the [packages.config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#:~:targetText=The%20packages.,server%2C%20without%20all%20those%20packages.) format and you can see the [global packages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders). If you use this mode, what you call a copy is just copied from the global folder into the project, which is the nuget package that your project actually USES, and then when compiled, the DLL will output from that package in the project into the output folder.

Comment: Also, you can see the reference in xx.csproj file and will find `<Reference Include=XXXXX> <HintPath>........<HintPath></Reference>` and hintpath is the nuget path in your solution. It is the actual path where you actually referenced the package. The output DLL is just a copy of this  package.

Comment: Yes, I am using packages.config with global packages folder and I'm both referencing this dll and copying mutiple versions of it into Resources for the application. So I have 2 nugets downloaded to the global packages, each one has 2 versions of this dll plus a copy of one of them copied by prebuild script, based on build configuration. All 4 original copies have Copy Local = true and should end up in Resources and one of the 2 instances copied by script is referenced in the project. What happens is that the reference's (hint) path gets changed to a copy from Resources now, after adding them.

Comment: l suspect you just reference the dlls that are copied by the script as content by some kind of automation.

Comment: (I'm not really allowed to share the project in public.) You see, the problem is that this all started when we added the 4 copies as content, to be copied to the Resources and the reference was not changed and it was always coming from different place (i.e. not from Resources). It has to be some VS automagic (or bug), that when you add a referenced DLL to Resources as content, it will get referenced from there automatically (and this also causes automatic copying it to debug folder) because there is nothing else that has changed and removing those resource copies fixes the problem immediately.